# in python 3.8 how to test a field annotated as Literal in a dataclass is valid at run

Tags: python, runtime, literals, typechecking, python-dataclasses

Given the following example:

```py
from typing import Literal
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
Class Example:
    answer: Literal['Y', 'N']

x = Example('N')
field = fields(x)[0]
```

How can I check that the variable field is of type Literal? `issubclass(field.type, Literal)` doesn't seem to work.

Secondly how can I then get the `list ['Y', 'N']` from `field.type`, so that I could check the value at run time and raise an error when `fail = Example('invalid')`

`pydantic` does this but you would have to use their drop in dataclass...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Literal` is not a normal type that a python object would have at runtime, it doesn't make sense to check that an object is a `Literal`

You can access the annotations for a class using `__annotations__`, following on from your example:

```
>>> Example.__annotations__['answer'].__args__
('Y', 'N')
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I ended up using this for my first question: ```hasattr(field.type, '__origin__') and getattr(field.type, "__origin__") is Literal
```
It does feel a little strange/inconsistent that if the type was int/Decimal/str then you could do issubclass(..) just not for Literals ...

And slightly shorter hand to get the latter: ```getattr(field, "__args__")```

Answer (score 1):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Literal

from validated_dc import ValidatedDC


@dataclass
class Example(ValidatedDC):
    answer: Literal['Y', 'N']


instance = Example('N')
assert instance.is_valid()


instance = Example('X')
assert not instance.is_valid()
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a tiny Python library for this purpose: https://github.com/tamuhey/dataclass_utils

This library can be applied for such dataclass that holds another dataclass (nested dataclass), and nested container type (like `Tuple[List[Dict...`).
Of course, it can test `Literal` at runtime.